# Is the use of "supermarket" the same as the one of "school / jail / prison / court / church"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

[Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/school_1?q=school) says that

> When a school is being referred to as an institution, you do not need
>   to use ***the***: *When do the children finish school?* When you are talking
>   about a particular building, ***the*** is used: *I’ll meet you outside the
>   school*. **Prison, jail, court,** and **church** work in the same way: *Her
>   husband spent three years in prison.*

So, when you say "*I go to school*", "**school**" is an uncountable noun & means a general teaching institution.

But, when you say "*I go to **the** school*" "**school**" is a countable noun & means a physical school building.

My question is that:

Do we apply that same principle to the word "**supermarket**"?

For example, "*I go to supermarket everyday*" (supermarket here is an uncountable noun & means a general supermarket)

"*I go to the supermarket everyday*" (supermarket here is a countable noun & means a physical supermarket building)

But in [Longman DIctionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/supermarket), "**supermarket**" is a countable noun only.

Comment: In AmE, we don't say "I'm going to supermarket" to mean to shop for groceries.  But in English generally we do say, "going *to market*".  I suppose we use the article because the supermarket is a relatively new thing, and "super" distinguished it from normal establishments, although nowdays few grocery stores are not supermarkets.

Comment: No, it is always a countable noun, you need to use an article with it. Out of interest, why do you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not idiomatic to say

> > we go to supermarket

although *going to market* has long been established usage.

Where supermarkets are concerned, one goes to *a supermarket* or *the supermarket*, for the time-being anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Tᴚoɯɐuo comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131540/is-the-use-of-supermarket-the-same-as-the-one-of-school-jail-prison-cou#comment264666_131540), there is an "article-less" usage *go to market* in English, but that one's extremely dated when used with the sense of *[a person] going to a market in order to buy things there*. It might still occur occasionally with the sense *...in order to **sell** things there*, but even that seems dated / dialectal / "rustic" to me. Today it's only likely to occur in contexts like *The new model goes to market next week* (but even that would more often be ***comes*** to market, or perhaps ***hits*** the market).

In all normal contexts, you'd *go to **the** supermarket*, regardless of whether you have any particular supermarket in mind (or indeed, whether there is more than one supermarket that you could *feasibly* be going to).